# Splitting a variable twice

Tags: javascript, variables, split

I have a variable `rowData` which gets something assigned to it:

```
rowData = wflogrows[i].split("~~");
```

When I use `console.log(wflogrows[i]);` **without** splitting I get the following:

```
Thu Oct 24 11:28:01 UTC+0200 2019~~Doe, John (i:0#.w|doejohn)~~00-Entwurf~~20-Vorgesetzter~~~~
```

After splitting I get

```
Doe, John (i:0#.w|doejohn)
```

How can I split this in such a way that I only get the name `Doe, John` without what is written in the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression `.match` instead - match `~~`, then match a word, followed by a comma and a space, and another word. Then extract everything after the `~~`:

```js
const str = 'Thu Oct 24 11:28:01 UTC+0200 2019~~Doe, John (i:0#.w|doejohn)~~00-Entwurf~~20-Vorgesetzter~~~~';
const match = str.match(/~~(\w+, \w+)/);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it on a space followed by a bracket.

```js
const name = 'Doe, John (i:0#.w|doejohn)'.split(' (')[0];
console.log(name)
```